# Show that $f$, defined on a closed cover of $X$, is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\mathbb{B}$ be a finite closed cover of a topological space $X$. For each $B \in \mathbb{B}$, let $f_B: B \to Y$ be continuous. Furthermore, suppose for each pair $A, B \in \mathbb{B}$, $f_A|_{A \cap B} = f_B|_{A \cap B}$. Then $f: X \to Y$, defined by $f(x) = f_A(x)$ for each $x \in A$ is continuous.

We just proved the Baire category theorem in topology, and our instructor hinted that it would be useful here, but I really don't see how. We don't know anything about either the space $X$ or the space $Y$, so it doesn't make sense to use it.

I started with just taking a closed set $C$ in $Y$. Then either it is entirely contained in the image of one of the $B$ sets, in which case $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed since $f_B$ is continuous. My problem is what happens when $C$ is contained in the image of several of the $B$ sets. Any hints will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C$ is closed in  $Y$, then
$$f^{-1}(C)=\bigcup_{B\in \mathbb{B}}f_B^{-1}(C).$$

Since $f_B$ is continuous, $f_B^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $B$, so $f_B^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$ as well (because $B$ is closed in $X$), so $f^{-1}(C)$ is a finite union of closed sets, hence closed.